# How to set up Google Sign In with Grails Spring Security Core?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to set up authentication to my Grails app with Google+ Sign In. Google deprecated their OpenID and they no longer allow new apps to authenticate that way.

I tried using the http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-oauth2-provider .

Once I've installed it, I have no clue what to do to make it actually authenticate. Can anyone fill in the missing blanks here? I've read the documentation, https://adaptivecomputing.github.io/grails-spring-security-oauth2-provider/docs/guide/index.html , but it deals mainly with configuration options and is not a how-to guide.

If anyone has either a sample project that's working and I can see the source, or can point me to the right reading material it would be great.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that there are plugins that do this out of the box. They are just not referenced in the Spring Security Core page (unlike all other extensions).

Here are the links: Plugin:

- http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-oauth-google

Dependencies:

- http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-oauth
- http://grails.org/plugin/oauth

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and spent quite a lot of time looking for a sample that works.

It appeared that the fastest way to achive that is to use [Spring Security OAuth plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-oauth)  +   [Google for Spring Security OAuth plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-oauth-google)

Sample project that really works is [here](https://github.com/bagage/grails-google-authentification-example) it uses grails 2.3.5 so use that version for starting it if you want to avoid any grails version compatibility issues.